# glLineWidth not taking effect?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

```
glColor4f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.8);
glLineWidth(100.0);
ccDrawCircle(ccp(240,160), 70, 0, 360, NO);
```

For some reason, the circle's line being drawn definitely hasn't 100 width. That code is inside the draw method and all. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you testing on an OpenGLES1.x device (iPhone, iPhone 3G, 1st and 2nd gen ipods). In my experience, values higher than one are only supported in OpenGLES 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two thoughts: first of all, your size might be bigger than the possible ranges for the value.  I seem to recall reading that an Open GL ES implementation actually only needs to support a value of 1.  I think the iPhone can support values other than 1, but 100 might be outside of its range.

You might also want to check if glLineSmooth is enabled and, if not, disable it.  But I don't think that that is the issue here.

Answer (score 4):

Try seeing what range the device supports for line widths:

```
GLint range[2];
glGetIntegerv(GL_ALIASED_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE, range);
glGetIntegerv(GL_SMOOTH_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE, range);
```

You are only guaranteed for 1.0 to be supported, but I do know that the iPhone supports at least 2.0 as well (I know a well-known game that uses 2.0 to render a line-drawn circle).

Comment: Does this 'range' get saved as [0] = max, [1] = min? I did this:     GLint smoothRange[2];
    glGetIntegerv(GL_SMOOTH_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE, smoothRange);
    cout << "GL_SMOOTH_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE: " << smoothRange[0] << " " << smoothWidthRange[1];

    GLint aliased[2];
    glGetIntegerv(GL_ALIASED_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE, aliased);
    cout << "GL_ALIASED_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE: " << aliased[0] << " " << aliased[1]; and got: GL_SMOOTH_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE: 1 0
GL_ALIASED_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE: 4226400 0

I can definitely set the line width > 1, but it seems to stop getting bigger about 10 or so.

Comment: Huh, what device is this happening on? It almost sounds like broken drivers that aren't fully supporting `glGetIntegerv` for the line parameters. As a sanity test, but sure to set `smoothRange` and `aliased` arrays to something known (like `0xdeadbabe`) to see if `glGetIntegerv` is even modifying your array. Maybe it's not. In which case, it's broken/unsupported/etc.

Comment: It is a Quadro NVS 420. Ah, you are right - the arrays are not modified by the glGetIntegerv calls at all. The only reason I'm trying to check this that I'm trying to set a large line width and it seems to clamp to about 10. I just wanted to see where that limit was actually coming from.

Comment: Oh, so this is on a computer (and not a mobile device)?? I'm quite surprised that it's not filling in those values. Something doesn't sound right. I would check `glError` right before calling `glGetIntegerv` and then call `glError` again right afterward. Maybe there is some underlying error preventing it from giving you those values (but I honestly can't imagine what; it's just copying a value from some internal structure to your variables).

Comment: Yes, it's a desktop computer. I did this:     GLenum err = glGetError();
    std::cout << "error before? " << err << std::endl;

    glGetIntegerv(GL_SMOOTH_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE, smoothRange);

    err = glGetError();
    std::cout << "error after? " << err << std::endl;

but both before and after it just outputs "0".

Comment: Ah, I did not have a glContext where I was trying to use these glGet functions. It works fine when I do have a context. Seems like a strange design that there is no error that indicates something like that, but it is working now. Thanks for the help, and sorry for the noise!

Comment: Huh, yeah, I would totally expect an error of some sort rather than `glGet*` silently returning when there's no context.